# Update files on a tomcat server, via Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I've recently found out how to remotely debug my java files on a Tomcat server via eclipse and was wondering something.  I am wondering if I could import the same files into Eclipse that are currently housed in the webapps folder on my tomcat server, and instead of having to go to that filepath anytime I need to make a code change with the files in the tomcat server, be able to make them directly in Eclipse which I would be using to debug anyway.

Currently I've tried importing the same project folder from the webapps folder in Tomcat into Eclipse and made a small code change, relaunched my server, but am not seeing the change in my tomcat library.

When importing into Eclipse does it make it's own separate instance of the files, instead of actually being able to import the same exact files as in the tomcat server?

Answer (score 0):

If you double-click the Tomcat server in the 'Servers' view inside Eclipse, you will see a configuration tab "Server Locations".
By default, eclipse doesn't make changes to the tomcat 'webapps' folder, it uses folders under its workspace.

Changing that option to 'Use tomcat installation' will make the changes be visible from the tomcat/webapps folder on your file system.